# Return an entry from a table based on criteria, which is not in another table

Tags: mysql

I need help with a query and i cant figure out how to make it work.

**Table1**

```
uid | G | L
------------ 
cde   2   1
fgk   1   2
kgl   2   1
```

**Table2**

```
uid1 |uid2
-----------
abc    cde
fgk    cde
mnm    kgl
```

I have a known uid which is

```
 uid | G | L
 -----------
 abc   1   2
```

and i must match this uid with one from **Table1**

My query for this is :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE G=2 AND L=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This will return:

```
cde   2   1
kgl   2   1
```

The query that i am looking for must return only `kgl` because `cde` is already paired with `abc` in **Table2**

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: With some tweaking i have come up with this query:

```
    SELECT uid FROM table1 AS t1 
    WHERE G = 1 AND L = 2 AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM table2 AS t2 
    WHERE (t1.uid = t2.uid1 OR t1.uid=t2.uid2) AND (t2.uid1 = 'abc' OR t2.uid2 = 'abc'))
```

Comment: `kgl` is also paired with `abc` in `Table2`

Comment: yeap, a smal typo, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT uid, G, L
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE G = 2 AND L = 1 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM Table2 AS t2
                      WHERE t1.uid = t2.uid2 AND t2.uid1 = 'abc')
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/650f4/1)

Comment: My first try was using not exists but it was failing w/o knowing the cause! This one saved me hours(and i spend 2-3 hours trying b4 posting for help).Thanks !